# Cassandra two dimensional data modelling

Tags: cassandra, bigdata, data-modeling, cql, cassandra-3.0

**The Use case:**

For a game I am collecting the results of each game match. It's always Team A against Team B. Each team consists of 5 players each picking a champion and the possible outcome of a match is for one team either Won / Lost or for both teams a draw.

I would like to figure out the best champion combinationsI want to create win/lose/draw statistics based on the chosen champion combination of each team. In total there are ~100 champions a player can chose from. So there are many different champion combinations possible.

More (bonus) features:

- I would like to figure out how one combination performed against another specific combination (in short: what's the best combination to counter a very strong champion combination)
- As balance changes are applied to the game it makes sense to have a possibility to select / filter stats by specific timeranges (for instance past 14 days only) - daily precision is fine for that

**My problem:**

I wonder what's the best way to collect the statistics based on the champion combination? How would the data modelling look like?

**My idea:**

1. Create a hash of all `championId` in a combination which would literally represent a `championCombinationId` which is a unique identifier for the champion combo a team uses.
2. Create a two dimensional table which allows tracking combination vs combination stats. Something like this:
   [image]

Timeframes (daily dates) and the actual `championId`s for a `combinationId` are missing there.

I tried myself creating a model for the above requirements, but I am absolutely not sure about it. Nor do I know what keys I would need to specify.

```
CREATE TABLE team_combination_statistics (
  combinationIdA text, // Team A
  combinationIdB text, // Team B
  championIdsA text, // An array of all champion IDs of combination A
  championIdsB text, // An array of all champion IDs of combination B
  trackingTimeFrame text, // A date?
  wins int,
  losses int,
  draws int
);
```

Comment: This is no a CQL request ! what tool are you using?? what KEYSPACE are you using and columFamily ... etc

Comment: It's just about the data modelling, it's not stored to Cassandra yet. Am i supposed to use a different tag than cassandra in that case?

Comment: I think yes, cos isn't really about cassandra, so i think you should talk about modelling data, merise or something like that may be you got a most idea than me i am no fluent in English so :) i hope you find an other topic name to don't confuse people looking at something isn't really talking about. ;) ty very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is quite long so I'll talk about different topics before suggesting my approach, be ready for a long answer:

1. Data normalization
2. Two-dimensional tables with same value axes

## Data normalization

Storing total ammount of data is useful but ordering by it isn't, as the order doesn't determine if a combination is good vs another, it determines the combination that most times have won/lost vs the opposite but the total ammount of games played also matters.

When ordering the results, you want to order by win-ratio, draw-ratio, loose-ratio of two of the previous as the third is a linear combination.

## Two-dimensional tables with same value axes

The problem on two-dimensional tables where both dimensions represent the same data, in this case a group of 5 champs, is that either you make a triangular table or you have data doubled as you will have to store cominationA vs combinationB and combinationB vs combinationA, being combinationX a specific group of 5 champs.

There are two aproaches here, using triangular tables or doubling the data manually:

### 1. Triangular tables:

You create a table where either the top right half is empty or the bottom left hand is empty. You then handle in the app which hash is A and which is B, and you may need to swap their order, as there is no duplicate data. You could for example consider alphabetical order where A < B always. If you then request the data in the wrong order you would get no data. The other option would be making both A vs B and B vs A query and then joining the results (swapping the wins and looses obviously).

### 2. Doubling the data manually:

By making two inserts with reflected values (A, B, wins, draws, looses & B, A, looses, draws, wins) you would duplicate the data. This lets you query in any order at the cost of using two times the space and requiring double inserts.

### Pros and cons:

The pros of one approach are the cons of the other.

#### Pros of triangular tables

- Does not store duplicate data
- Requires half the insert

#### Pros of doubling the data

- The application doesn't care in which order you make the request

I would probably use the triangular tables approach as the application complexity increase is not that big to be relevant, but the scalability does matter.

## Proposed schema

Use whatever keyspace you want, I choose so from stackoverflow. Modify the replication strategy or factor as needed.

```
CREATE KEYSPACE so WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 3};
```

### Champion names table

The champion table will contain info about the different champions, for now it will only hold the name but you could store other things in the future.

```
CREATE TABLE so.champions (
    c boolean,
    id smallint,
    name text,
    PRIMARY KEY(c, id)
) WITH comment='Champion names';
```

A `boolean` is used as the partition key as we want to store all champs in a single partition for query performance and there will be a low ammount of records (~100) we will always be using `c=True`. A `smallint` was choosen for the `id` as 2^7 = 128 was to close to the actual number of champs and to leave room for future champs without using the negative numbers.

When querying the champs you could get them all by doing:

```
SELECT id, name FROM so.champions WHERE c=True;
```

or request a specific one by:

```
SELECT name FROM so.champions WHERE c=True and id=XX;
```

### Historic match results table

This table will store the results of the matches without agregating:

```
CREATE TABLE so.matches (
    dt date,
    ts time,
    id XXXXXXXX,
    teams list<frozen<set<smallint>>>,
    winA boolean,
    winB boolean,
    PRIMARY KEY(dt, ts, id)
) WITH comment='Match results';
```

For the partition of an historic data table, and as you mentioned daily precission, `date` seems to be a nice partition key. A `time` column is used as the first clustering key for ordering reasons and to complete the timestamp, doesn't matter if these timestamp belong to the ending or finishing instant, choose one and stick with it. An additional identifier is required in the clustering key as 2 games may end in the same instant (time has nanosecond precission which would basically mean that the data lost to overlap would be quite insignificant but your data source will probably not have this precission, thus making this last key column necesary). You can use whatever type you want for this column, probably you will already have some king of identifier with the data that you can use here. You could also go for a random number, an incremental int managed by the application, or even the name of the first players as you can be sure the same player will not start/finish two games at the same second.

The `teams` column is the most important one: it stores the ids of the champs that were played in the game. A sequence of two elements is used, one for each team. The inner (frozen) set is for the champs id in each team, for example: `{1,3,5,7,9}`. I've tried a couple different options: `set< frozen<set<smallint>> >`, `tuple< set<smallint>> , set<smallint> >` and `list< frozen<set<smallint>> >`. The first options doesn't store the order of the teams, so we would have no way to know who win the game. The second one doesn't accept using an index on this column and doing partial searchs through `CONTAINS` so I've opted for the third that does keep the order and allows partial searchs.

The other two values are two booleans representing who won the game. You could have additional columns such a `draw boolean` one but this one is not necesary or `duration time` if you want to store the length of the game (I'm not using Cassandra's `duration` type on purpouse as it is only worth when it takes months or at least days), `end timestamp`/`start timestamp` if you want to store the one that you are not using in the partition and clustering key, etc.

#### Partial searchs

It may be useful to create an index on teams so that you are allowed to query on this column:

```
CREATE INDEX matchesByTeams ON so.matches( teams );
```

Then we can execute the following `SELECT` statenments:

```
SELECT * FROM so.matches WHERE teams CONTAINS {1,3,5,7,9};
SELECT * FROM so.matches WHERE teams CONTAINS {1,3,5,7,9} AND dt=toDate(now());
```

The first one would select the matches in which any of the teams selected that composition and the second one will further filter it to today's matches.

### Stats cache table

With these two tables you can hold all the info, and then request the data you need to calculate the stats involved. Once you calculate some data, you could store this info back in Cassandra as a "cache" in an additional table so that when a user requests some stats to be shown, you first check if they were already calculated and if they weren't calculate. This table would need to have a column for each parameter that the user can enter, for example: champion composition, starting date, final date, enemy team; and additional columns for the stats themselves.

```
CREATE TABLE so.stats (
    team frozen<set<smallint>>,
    s_ts timestamp,
    e_ts timestamp,
    enemy frozen<set<smallint>>,
    win_ratio float,
    loose_ratio float,
    wins int,
    draws int,
    looses int,
    PRIMARY KEY(team, s_ts, e_ts, enemy)
) WITH comment="Already calculated queries";
```

#### Ordered by win/loose ratios:

To get the results order by ratios instead of enemy team you can use materialized views.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW so.statsByWinRatio AS
    SELECT * FROM so.stats
    WHERE team IS NOT NULL AND s_ts IS NOT NULL AND e_ts IS NOT NULL AND win_ratio IS NOT NULL AND enemy IS NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY(team, s_ts, e_ts, win_ratio, enemy)
    WITH comment='Allow ordering by win ratio';
```

**NOTE:**
While I was answering I realized that introducing the concept of "patch" inside the DB so that the user is not allowed to determine dates but patches could be a better solution. If you are interested comment and I'll edit the answer to include the patch concept. It would mean modifying both the `so.historic` and `so.stats` tables a bit, but quite minor changes.

Comment: Wow, thanks for such a detailed answer. I read it yesterday and I am impressed that you've taken care of a couple details which I haven't even mentioned. I tried to read up a bout a "patch concept" for Cassandra but I haven't found anything. I would be very happy to learn about it too!

Comment: As of the matches table. I would be looking for a `GROUP BY` query there in order to get the top champion combinations within the past 30 days, having at least 1000 times recorded in the database. How would you query that? And how would a query look like to fill the "cache" table for a specific set of of champion ids. More precise: I am not sure how I can technically figure out what set of the `teams` list won the match. Also wouldn't it be wise to add clustering order by `dt` and `ts` descending in the matches table? What about using `teams` as partition key on matches?

Comment: @kentor By patches I mean the different balance changes you mentioned, not about Cassandra (C*). It seems we are talking about a MOBA game and those balancing changes will usually have a patch asociated. Am I mistaken? If I'm not, we could change the way that data is sorted by date and instead sort it by patch. winA=True (=>winB=False) means that the first set in the list won, winB=True (=>winA=False) means that the second set in the list won, and winA=winB=False means that it was a draw.

Comment: Using `teams` as a partition key on matches would mean too many partitions, the `teams` set of posibilities is quite big, its not a combination (where order doesn't matter) nor a permutation (where order does matter) as it only matters if you place them in the first or second team. But it is over 75 million, which would mean too many partitions.

Comment: @kentor by the way, the `time` fot `timestamp` correction that you suggested was not what I wanted. `timestamp` stores date and time (ms) info while `date` only stores the date and `time` only stored the time (ns). As I already have `dt date`, `ts time` will hold the rest of the info. If I swap to the patch approach those two columns would be merged into a single `ts timestamp` as the partition key would be the patch.

Comment: Oh sorry for that @Adirio. I couldn't find anything about a `time` datatype in the datastax documentation here: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html , hence I thought it was just a mistake? Yes you are right that it's about a MOBA game, unfortunately I don't have a way to receive information about patches automatically so I prefer the timestamp approach at the moment. I am currently trying your approach and I hope I can ask more questions while I am proceeding

Comment: @kentor try to make a simple table with a `time` column to verify if your version has that type but it should as specified in [the docs](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/types.html).

Comment: When I insert a set of champion ids, do I need to order the set of champion ids? Does it matter if I insert {3, 2, 1} or {1, 2, 3} for each set?

Comment: @kentor No, it doesn't matter, thats the advantage of using a set, it orders the elements itself internally and avoids duplicates (MOBA games usually don't allow the same champion twice in a team except for fun scenarios). If any of these restrictions doesn't suit you, this is, if you need a specific order instead of letting the set order them or if you need duplicates then you could swap the set for a list, and then use `[3,1,2]`

Comment: You are right, there is a game mode which would allow a duplicate champion id. Is it possible to allow duplicates? That's going to be my last question, thanks for answering all my questions :-)

Comment: Don't worry, questions are welcome. Is the duplicate champ mode an all-players-in-the-team-play-the-same-champ mode? If it was like that just use {ID} and let your app know that if the length of the set is 1 is that kind of game.

Comment: If not, you would need to swap the `list<frozen<set<smallint>>>` for a `list<frozen<list<smallint>>>` and insert them with sqaure brackets for all: `[ [1,2,3,4,4] , [5,6,7,8,9] ]`. Keep in mind one thing: you will always need to sort the list in your application because if you store data with `[1,2,2,3,3]` and you query with `[1,2,3,2,3]` they will **NOT** match. This problem was solved with sets as they get ordered internally. So stick to the set if you are only considering the duplicates special case as all champs in a team equal to each other.

Comment: sorry for asking another question, I am really struggling with aggegating my data so that I get useful stats from my `matches` table. For the teams I am using a `list<frozen<list<int>>>` now. Could you edit two select queries which would give results to the following questions: 1. What champion combinations have the best win ratio between date x and y, having at least 1000 records in my table. 2. What's the win ratio/amount of games for a specific champion combination.

Comment: @kentor 1: In the `matches` table you have no info about win-/loose-ratio, each row is a match's raw info. As we are using the date column as a partition key in `matches`, you will have to query this table for every date in the desired interval (`SELECT * FROM so.matches WHERE dt=XXX`), compute all the stats for all the matches in the desired interval and store it in the `stats` table. This table should be a bit different if you want this kind of query. As I told you, the DB schema is defined by the queries, make an exhaustive list of them and edit your OP to reflect the changes.

Comment: I think I mentioned that in the op, computing that might take quite long due to the amount of data I get. What would you do to answer the above questions?

Comment: @Adirio, @kentor - Please note that creating a secondary index on columns with high cardinality is not advisable. See [reference](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useWhenIndex.html#useWhenIndex__when-no-index) for further info. When you access the `so.matches` using `teams` column, query scans multiple partitions and it's probably going to be slow after number of matches gets too big.

Comment: @Oresztesz Yes, you are right, the secondary index there may not be a good idea for that column.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a statistics table which holds game stats for a champion in a given day.

```
CREATE TABLE champion_stats_by_day (
    champion_ids FROZEN<SET<INT>>,
    competing_champion_ids FROZEN<SET<INT>>,
    competition_day DATE,
    win_ratio DECIMAL,
    loss_ratio DECIMAL,
    draw_ratio DECIMAL,
    wins INT,
    draws INT,
    losses INT,
    matches INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(champion_ids, competition_day, competing_champion_ids)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY(competition_day DESC, competing_champion_ids ASC);
```

You can ask stats for a champion starting from a certain date, but you have to do the sorting / aggregation in the clients:

```
SELECT * FROM champion_stats_by_day WHERE champion_ids = {1,2,3,4} AND competition_day > '2017-10-17';

 champion_ids | competition_day | competing_champion_ids | draw_ratio | draws | loss_ratio | losses | matches | win_ratio | wins
--------------+-----------------+------------------------+------------+-------+------------+--------+---------+-----------+------
 {1, 2, 3, 4} |      2017-11-01 |         {2, 9, 21, 33} |       0.04 |     4 |       0.57 |     48 |      84 |      0.38 |   32
 {1, 2, 3, 4} |      2017-11-01 |         {5, 6, 22, 32} |      0.008 |     2 |       0.55 |    128 |     229 |      0.43 |   99
 {1, 2, 3, 4} |      2017-11-01 |       {12, 21, 33, 55} |       0.04 |     4 |       0.57 |     48 |      84 |      0.38 |   32
 {1, 2, 3, 4} |      2017-10-29 |         {3, 8, 21, 42} |          0 |     0 |      0.992 |    128 |     129 |     0.007 |    1
 {1, 2, 3, 4} |      2017-10-28 |         {2, 9, 21, 33} |       0.23 |    40 |       0.04 |      8 |     169 |      0.71 |  121
 {1, 2, 3, 4} |      2017-10-22 |        {7, 12, 23, 44} |       0.57 |    64 |       0.02 |      3 |     112 |       0.4 |   45
```

Update & insert works as following. You first select the existing statistic for that date and champion ID and then do an update. In case, when row is not in the table it's not going to be a problem as Cassandra performs and `UPSERT` in this case.:

```
SELECT * FROM champion_stats_by_day WHERE champion_ids = {1,2,3,4} AND competing_champion_ids = {21,2,9,33} AND competition_day = '2017-11-01';
UPDATE champion_stats_by_day
    SET win_ratio = 0.38, draw_ratio = 0.04, loss_ratio = 0.57, wins = 32, draws = 4, losses = 48, matches = 84
    WHERE champion_ids = {1,2,3,4}
    AND competing_champion_ids = {21,2,9,33} 
    AND competition_day = '2017-11-01';
```

I also added the sample CQL commands [here](https://gist.github.com/gitaroktato/d81a30b77dbe695aa2a3b49bf475f08b).
Let me know what you think.

Comment: Ordering not-normalized data will just place most common combinations at top.

Comment: @Adirio - which table & column are you referring to? It's considered to be a good practice to mention all columns in `WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY`. That's why I added `competing_champion_ids`

Comment: I'm refering to win, draw and loss, they are integer values and ordering by them won't be that useful. You will probably want to store win-ratio, draw-ratio and loss-ratio (or maybe just two of these as the third is linearly dependant) as percentages and use them as clustering keys leaving the integers as normal columns.

Comment: Adirio is right I think. A couple questions regarding the champion_stats table. 1. What about the time component, that wouldn't allow me to get the stats of the past x days only. Should I simply add a day date as clustering col? 2. A ratio makes sense and I also thought about a total_games in order to filter rare matchups as ratios wouldn't be accurate.  3. (Why) Is it necessary to use win/loss/draw as cluster column? I would prefer running an update which increments these fields. It would also require a counter field instead of int or?

Comment: @kentor Take a look at my answer (I was writting it, its quite long) and make any comment there so that I can modify it (maybe not today though).

Comment: @Adirio - you are right, 1500 wins and 1500 losses should be ranked lower, than let's say 250 wins and 3 losses.

Comment: @kentor - Reflecting to your questions: 1. You can add filter-by date, in this case you should maintain wins/draws/losses fields per day, which is complicating writes. Also you have to aggregate&sort results in your client after you've read recent matches for a given champion.

Comment: 3. Update is not possible in Cassandra for clustering columns, that's why added a delete/insert in batch.  If you add counter for any field in a table, that table is considered a [counter table](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCountersConcept.html). Counter tables have special rules, so it's a bit more complicated to use them. For example you can't use a ratio field and a counter field in the same table.